# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'image'

Tags: python, tensorflow

This code worked just fine yesterday:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import cv2

augmentedImageLeftRight = tf.image.random_flip_left_right(srcImage)
cv2.imshow('image', augmentedImageLeftRight)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Today I added this line:

```
augmentedRotation = tf.image.rot90(srcImage, k=2)
```

After I added this code I got the following error message:

```
augmentedImageLeftRight = tf.image.random_flip_left_right(srcImage)
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'image'
```

I literally changed nothing else. Even if I delete the row I added it still does not work.

EDIT:
Sh*t. My entire code broke. I did nothing but start PyCharm and add one line. I just realized that I can't run any file in the whole directory anymore. Every file gives me an error when importing something from TF or Keras. There are so many error message I don't know where to begin. I can't post them all here. I just pushed it my 'test' branch in GitHub. Pls someone have look. I don't understand a thing what's going on right now. 
https://github.com/Daniel-Fauland/TrafficSignClassification/tree/test

EDIT2:
I can't run my main file as well If I run "predictValidationData" which just calls the run function in the file "trafficSignsClassification" I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Maximal/Documents/Python/PyCharm/TrafficSignClassification/run/predictValidationData.py", line 1, in <module>
    from model.trafficSignsClassification import Model
  File "C:\Users\Maximal\Documents\Python\PyCharm\TrafficSignClassification\model\trafficSignsClassification.py", line 3, in <module>
    from tensorflow import keras
ImportError: cannot import name 'keras'
```

Seems like I can't import anything that is related to Tensorflow somehow. Numpy, pandas, matplotlib work fine. I did not change directory or moved any file/folder. I did not install/uninstall any python package.
One thing maybe has to do sth with it was the code I added:

```
tf.image.rot90(x, tf.random_uniform(shape=[], minval=0, maxval=4, dtype=tf.int32))
```

I tried ti implement sth like this but PyCharm highlighted the "random_uniform" A message that popped up said sth about a random_uniform function/declaration in a **init**.py I just thought ok whatever I don't know what this is so I closed the window and deleted the random_uniform part. After that every TF import in the whole project isn't working anymore. Unfortunately I did not screenshot the window nor do I know the exact message.

Comment: Show us the entire error message, including full stack trace.

Comment: Check the version of tensorflow. Using `pip list` check if tensorflow is still installed and up to date.

Comment: did you modify your environment in some way, like installing/removing/updating some packages?

Comment: @RayanRal Probably PyCharm just modified sth for me in the background when I clicked on the random_uniform line which was highlighted in PyCharm. Check my newest edit. That is erverything I know about this

Comment: Provide the smallest reproducible piece of code. for example, `import tensorflow as tf; tf.image`

Comment: @Daniel stupid idea, but could you try just re-installing tensorflow?
One thought I have is that PyCharm actually allows navigating to lib sources directly, and you could've accidentally remove/modify something there, which led to errors in TF.

Comment: @RayanRal I just reinstalled it and it works again. PyCharm somehow messed up my tf package. Thank you very much for the quick fix!

Answer (score 0):

@jakub
I just created a new project in PyCharm and tried to import a module from tf. Even that does not work. PyCharm changed the module tf somehow.

[image: TF_error]